# Excel VBA why an If statement in For Each doesn't catch all rows in the selection?

Tags: excel, vba

Can any one see why in vba a for each doesn't catch all rows that meet the if statement condition? This simple method below will delete a row if it contains cells with a length of 3. It deletes some but not all but will eventually delete all if I keep running it.

```
Sub delete_3Digit_Numbers()
     For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Value <> "" And Len(cell.Value) = 3 Then
            Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
     Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA why an If statement in For Each doesn't catch all rows in the selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74165504/excel-vba-why-an-if-statement-in-for-each-doesnt-catch-all-rows-in-the-selectio)

Comment: ^^ link to same post?

Comment: if you look at the way the for each actual scans it moves forward a row each time (despite the row being removed).  I.e. if a row 2 is removed by your statement the next cell will be in row 3.  Therefore the row that was moved into row 2 by your statement will never be considered

Comment: You should iterate backwards, or even better create a `Union` Range and delete its rows at once of the code end. In such a loop, after row deletion, the reference for the next one is lost...

Answer (score 3):

Please, try the next way. The code will be faster, anyhow:

```
Sub delete_3Digit_Numbers()
    Dim cell As Range, rngDel As Range
     For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Value <> "" And Len(cell.Value) = 3 Then
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = cell
            Else
               Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, cell)
            End If
        End If
     Next cell
     If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

As I said in my above comment, using your way of iteration looses the reference for the following cell after a row deletion. You should iterate backwards, or use a `Union` range, as the above code does. Anyhow, deleting one row at a time consumes time and for a big range, the code is slow. using the above code, which deletes the rows at the end is obviously faster.